# Basic Formatting Issue

Tags: python, variables, syntax, formatting

This script doesn't work, is there a way that is similar to achieve this ?

Summary: I'm trying to break

```
top_left = (1650, 1050)
```

into 2 variables so I'd have r = 1680 and t = 1050

```
top_left = (r=1650, t=1050)

print (top_left)

print(r)
print(t)


raw_input()
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated,

Respectfully,
Spanjer

Edit,

Just to clear things up because i feel like i explained things badly, what i'm trying to do is take the output from top_left and turn it into 2 variables which i could input into another thing. (lets say a mouse movement(x,y))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want two variables from the elements in the tuple use:

```
In [6]: top_left = (1650, 1050)

In [7]: r,t=top_left 

In [8]: r
Out[8]: 1650

In [9]: t
Out[9]: 1050


top_left = (1650, 1050) # this called tuple packing

r,t=top_left # is tuple unpacking
```

If you want a particular element you can use indexing:

```
r=top_left[0]    
In [8]: r
Out[8]: 1650
```

Comment: Thank you very much such a simple issue but very import to solve!

Hey this seems like a logical way to do this, but i seem to be getting a syntax error what do you think it's being caused by ?

Comment: don't include `In [8]: ` etc.. that is my ipython shell output.

Comment: @Scorpion_God, I just wrote that and how is your answer different to mine?

Comment: Thank's alot i got it working Tuple packing is very handy :)

For the newbs out there here's the final code: 
`top_left = (1650, 1050)

r,t=top_left `

Comment: It was different when I posted it because you didn't mention that it was called tuple unpacking. When I commented, your comment hadn't come through.

Answer (score 1):

It does not work because `top_left = (r=1650, t=1050)` is not valid. What is your purpose? If you try to set each variable in one line you can do that like;

```
top_left,r,t = (1650, 1050), 1650, 1050
```

Comment: sorry I wrote the title incorrectly to begin with what I'm trying to do is take the output of top_left = (1680, 1050) which has 2 values and split that into 2 separate variables(r and t) so i can use them separately (in lets say print (r) print (t)

Comment: No problem. You can set it like 'r,t = top_left' or you can reach each value with index number like;
r = top_left[0]
t = top_left[1]

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> mouse_pos = (537, 285)
>>> x, y = mouse_pos
>>> x
537
>>> y
285
```

This process is called tuple unpacking.

Comment: Thanks alot for the answer it's 100% valid and appeals to my exact use, I'm really happy that there's people that are ready to help at a moments notice, it's really speeding up my education process.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
top_left = ((1650, 1050))
are_tee = ('r', 't')
pos = dict(zip(are_tee, top_left))
>>>pos['t']
>>>1050
```

A work around possibly, not quite what you are requesting.